# How can I update different columns of the same record in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I T-SQL update records with same PlayerName and PlayerCode but different season value with BornDateKey field corresponding to 2021-2022 season. The input and output I want to do is as follows.

Input:

| PlayerName | PlayerCode | Season | BornDateKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lionel Messi | d70ce98e | 2020-2021 |  |
| Lionel Messi | d70ce98e | 2021-2022 | 19870624 |
| Robert Lewandowski | 8d78e732 | 2020-2021 |  |
| Robert Lewandowski | 8d78e732 | 2021-2022 | 19880821 |

Output (expected):

| PlayerName | PlayerCode | Season | BornDateKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lionel Messi | d70ce98e | 2020-2021 | 19870624 |
| Lionel Messi | d70ce98e | 2021-2022 | 19870624 |
| Robert Lewandowski | 8d78e732 | 2020-2021 | 19880821 |
| Robert Lewandowski | 8d78e732 | 2021-2022 | 19880821 |

Comment: Seems like the date born (and Name) shouldn't be in the table at all, and should be in a separate table with the player data. Then you can't end up with inconsistencies like the above.

Comment: An `UPDATE` statement doesn't really have "output"... do you mean you want the data to look like that after your statement completes?

Comment: Please post your `CREATE TABLE` statements. We really can't help you with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an updatable CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MAX(BornDateKey) OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerCode) AS MaxBornDateKey
    FROM yourTable
)

UPDATE cte
SET BornDateKey = MaxBornDateKey
WHERE BornDateKey IS NULL;
```

If you instead want to *view* your data this way, then just select from the above CTE and use `MaxBornDateKey` as the `BornDateKey` value.

Comment: Updatable-CTEs weird me out. _Just how_ does SQL Server know which CTE rows correspond to which physical source rows? It's all _sourcery_ to me...

Comment: @Dai ... and that could be a good SO question, assuming it hasn't already been asked here already.

Comment: It's like magic, it doesn't need to be explained.

Comment: @marc_s Not tables, but individual _rows_. T-SQL doesn't have hidden `rowid` values or pseudocolumns unlike SQLite or Oracle - and (as far as I know) PK column metadata is not carried through derived tables.

Comment: The thing you need to remember is that a CTE is effectively resolved as an expression, @Dai (common table **expression**), and SQL Server has no problems updating a table with an expression.

Comment: @Larnu Please elaborate on "updating a table with an expression"

Comment: `SET YourColumn = CASE AnotherColumn WHEN 1 then 'a' ELSE 'b' END` for example, @Dai . Or even `... = AnotherColumn * 2 + 7`

Comment: @Larnu  That's not my question though, I'm wanting to know how SQL Server can map a _row_ in a derived-table-expression (including CTEs, VIEWs, and arbitrary `FROM` clauses) back to a physical row on-disk.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression they are different rows; they aren't. But like Tim said, you're better off asking a new question, @Dai . Possibly on [DBA.se] but I suspect there is already an answer there.

Comment: @Dai It's because if it can trace the columns through derived tables back to the source table without modification or grouping, then it will allow you to update that column. AFAIK in such an event it *will* feed the clustering key through. See eg https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0f841bdfd681657804dad42c34b95128 the clustering key was output into the plan even though there is no mention of it in the query

Comment: @Dai See also the rules for updatable views https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#updatable-views and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/modify-data-through-a-view?view=sql-server-ver15